# Separating present perfect verbs by a comma?

Tags: grammar, writing-style

I know this might seem trivial, but I am not sure what to do with sentences like this. If I have a sequence of verbs that I want to be in the present perfect tense how should I write the sentence.

> I have sung a song, broken a window, and scared the audience.

or should it be

> I have sung a song, have broken a window, and have scared the audience.

Comment: Your first sentence is fine.  Consider, "I ran, played, and read books during my vacation." Or "I have read, edited, and reformatted your manuscript."  The subject "I" has not changed nor has the tense.

Answer (score 1):

> I have sung a song, broken a window, and scared the audience

and

> I have sung a song, have broken a window, and have scared the audience

and

> I have sung a song, I have broken a window, and I have scared the
>   audience

are all grammatical. For brevity, we use the first.

Comment: Doesn't the third one have a comma splice? @Jasper Loy